# Unexpected "color" transition in half transparent cylinder with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, transparency

I try to represent red and blue spheres moving in a tube, and render it with Cycles. I made a part of the tube opaque and another part semi-transparent following the "color based on height" trick. I get the following result, but I am anoyed by the color transition that takes place at the third sphere (from the bottom right). It does not seem to depend on the orientation of the sun.
[image]

I built a minimal working example, with a half-transparent cylinder and got the same effect. The corresponding Blender file can be found [here](https://www.pct.espci.fr/~vdemery/files/test_cylinder_cycles.blend). The effect is not present if the cylinder is opaque.
[image]

Do you have any idea where this effect come from and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the reason of this shading 'glitch' is topology of your **Cylinder**. I don't know exactly why this is happening, maybe because of stretched faces (or for sure). When you scale it down on the X axis (to make it shorter) problem disappears.

[image: final]

### You have two options:

1. Add **Subdivision Surface** modifier.

[image: 1]

2. Add **Loop Cut** in the middle of the **Cylinder** (or couple of them to be sure that it doesn't happen again.

[image: 2]

Personally I would go with second one as this is 'lighter' solution.